# dotted line in Firefox with clip-path/poligon/rotate

Tags: css, rotation, transform, polygon, clip-path

I try to draw a rectangle with clip-path and rotate it.
However in Firefox (not in Chrome!) there's a small dotted line around the original size of the div.

```
<div id="triangle"></div>
#triangle {
 background-color: rgb(158, 0, 0);
 width: 82.5mm;
 height: 50mm;
 transform: rotate(15deg);
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75% 100%, 100% 50%);
}
```

[image: dotted line in firefox]

See https://jsfiddle.net/74bit/fvpky15r/9/

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this line?

Thanks,
Witold

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1671784

Add a parent div to your triangle div and add border-radius: 0.01px and overflow hidden to parent div.

```css
.parent-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 0.01px;
  width: 100mm;
  height: 100mm;
}
#triangle {
    background-color: rgb(158, 0, 0);
    width: 82.5mm;
    height: 50mm;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 75% 100%, 100% 50%);
    transition:transform .6s;
}

#triangle:hover{
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
         <div class="parent-container">
           <div id="triangle">
           
           </div>
         </div>
```